# Significance of homogeneous equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I'm studying ODE.

Over my math education career, I've occasionally encountered reference to homogeneous equations. Now, in ODE, I'm learning how to solve differential equations that are homogeneous. I've learned how to do this technique and how to recognize a homogeneous equation (and its order).

What I'm not so sure about is the significance of a homogeneous equation. Is it just a type of equation that lends itself to particular solutions? Does the fact that it represents an equation dependent on some ratio between x and y matter? Is there some physical significance to homogeneous equations?

Comment: I'm curious as well! Dropped out of my DE class once upon a time, just about when these got introduced. Now I'm back years later trying to learn DE again and, Homogeneity it's not well motivated (in ODE by Tenenbaum & Pollock, anyway).

It's also confusing that at first sight: first-order DE, second-order DE, and linear equation homogeneity seem to refer to slightly different things. I'm sure there's something relating them but it's not made transparent.

Comment: @sloth: Yes, there are 2 concepts of "homogeneous DE" that are in common use. Once the homogeneous version of a linear DE, giving the "complementary solution", and second the degree-homogeneous DE $y'=f(x,y)$ with $f(rx,ry)=r^\alpha f(x,y)$, that is, using homogeneous functions in the algebraic sense.

Comment: @ OP : What kind of "homogeneous" are you interested in? Speaking of $y/x$ ratios, it appears to be the algebraic kind. "Recognizing the order" I would slightly more associate with the linear kind of "homogeneous".

Answer (score 0):

Definition of Homogeneous ODE,

copy from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html :

A linear ordinary differential equation of order $n$ is said to be homogeneous if it is of the form
$$a_n(x)y^ {(n)}+a_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}+...+a_1(x)y'+a_0(x)y=0$$

where $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$, i.e., if all the terms are proportional to a derivative of $y$ (or $y$ itself) and there is no term that contains a function of $x$ alone.

However, there is also another entirely different meaning for a first-order ordinary differential equation. Such an equation is said to be homogeneous if it can be written in the form

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=F\left(\frac{y}{x} \right).$$

Such equations can be solved in closed form by the change of variables $u=\frac{y}{x}$ which transforms the equation into the separable equation
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{F(u)-u}.$$

NOTE : The bounty is not for me. It should be given to the author of the above citation.